# How do I isolate the 'second' component from a datetime in KDB?

Tags: kdb

Let's say I have a KDB datetime. How do I isolate the 'second' part of it:

```
2022.02.01D14:30:12.391424612
```

so that would be `12`?

I've tried `t.second`, but this brings back a time rather than integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
q)`ss $ 2022.02.01D14:30:12.391424612
12i
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! Is it possible to extend the same solution to 'minute' - so in this case it would return `30`?

Comment: `uu $ 2022.02.01D14:30:12.391424612

Comment: See [Cast](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cast/) at code.kx.com/q/ref

Answer (score 0):

you can also simply use

q)v:2022.02.01D14:30:12.391424612

q)v.ss

12i

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).